# Prevent form data accumulation when using React Hook Form on a multi-step dynamically generated form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a multi-step (multi-page) form whose content is dynamically generated. In other words, depending on the answer to a question on a previous step, a different question can be asked.

I am trying to use React Hook Forms for it and so, my form is structured something like this:

```
const MultiPageDynamicForm = () => {
    const formMethods = useForm()
    const { handleSubmit } = formMethods
    const formContent = useSelector(state => state.formContent)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const onSubmit = (data, event) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        // Submits the data for one step and gets the content for the next step
        // and stores in Redux state.
        dispatch(submitForm(data))

        // My problem is that the data parameter keeps accumulating
        // values for previous steps even when the form no longer shows those inputs.
    }

    return (
        <FormProvider {...formMethods}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <GenericInput type={formContent.inputType} /> // This component renders a different input type depending on the inputType parameter
                <button type="submit">Next</button>
            </form>
        </FormProvider>
    )
}
```

As noted in the code snippet above, my problem is that the `data` parameter given when calling `onSubmit` keeps accumulating the key,value pairs for all the previous inputs submitted rather than just showing the input value submitted for that particular step.

So if I have a three step form and I ask for first name on step 1, email on step 2 and birthdate on step 3, the `data` parameter will accumulate previous values like:

```
{ name: 'Bob' } // Step 1
{ name: 'Bob', email: 'bob@example.com' } // Step 2
{ name: 'Bob', email: 'bob@example.com', dob: '01/02/2003' } // Step 3
```

Instead, I only want it to contain the values submitted *for that particular step*.

```
Step 1: { name: 'Bob' } // Step 1
Step 2: { email: 'bob@example.com' } // Step 2
Step 3: { dob: '01/02/2003' } // Step 3
```

Is there a way to clear out the data state on a multi-step dynamic form each time? I'm storing each subsequent step's responses in Redux already so I don't need React Hook Form to do it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reset` function is what I needed.

Therefore, I needed something like:

```
const { handleSubmit, reset } = useForm()

useEffect(() => {
    reset() // Clear out React Hook Form state between each page/step of the wizard form.
    
    ...
    
}, [reset])
```